# Django URL Pattern Syntax - raw string

Tags: django, path, django-urls, url-pattern, rawstring

What is the difference between:

```
path('index/', views...
```

And

```
path(r'^index/$', views...
```

I use the first example but I see everyone using the raw string syntax in examples I look up. Are there any differences between the way Django handles the two examples?

Comment: The second one not path but re_path which is regex pattern check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

The `path` method is the *full match method*, so when your path will be exactly as described, you will have the possibility to handle the request with the view that you've described.

The `re_path` allows you more control with regular expressions.
Let's extend your example `r"^index/?$"`, here "?" sign allows the user to use the trailing slash "/" at the end of the URL or not use.

You can play with regexp here: https://regex101.com

The Django documentation about re_path is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

The business needs could be very complex and maybe you won't be able to make a match for a needed URL format with just the `path` features, but in 99% this option will be enough.